# Why does pip install in the Python38 folder, instead of the Python311 folder?

Tags: python, pip

I keep trying to install pip in various different ways, yet everytime I try to, it does not work. I tried to investigate by going to the Python folder in C:\Users(my pc name)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python, and even after I deleted my previous Python folders, uninstalled and fixed my PATH variables. Any clue why this is happening?

Update: No solution has been found, so for now I'm going to hard-reset python by uninstalling everything, then trying to reinstall and such. I'll make a second update if what I try works.

Update 2: Got the same error, so reverted back to 3.10.9, and it was completely fixed. Not sure why 3.11.1 doesn't work with my pc, but I fixed it by updating my pip.ini file in %APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini .

Comment: _I keep trying to install pip in various different ways_ Show us the exact command(s) you are using.

Comment: I tried manual since "py -m pip install --upgrade pip" didn't work for upgrading it, and it said successfully installed but since i'm using python 3.11 it didn't respond when I tried to type "pip --help" or "pip".

Comment: but even manually installing the files would just install the files to Python38 when I ran the file

Comment: Your `py` command must default to version 3.8.  Is there a way to run `py` and choose a different version?

Comment: I want to try and figure that out as well. I never installed 3.8 ever, so I don't know why pip defaults to 3.8

Comment: I believe `py -3.11` is the way to run a specific version.

Comment: of course, but it still doesn't let me install pip

Comment: Show us the full output of `pip --version`

Comment: I can't even type pip bro it says pip isnt a variable or command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your case older python was installed before latest. Overlap happend in namespase, when new python took `python` name, but new `pip` dont.

That issue occurs because `pip` is actually separate from python. And it have new lead number versions often, which probably occured in betwin your python versions installations.

Deleting `all Python versions` and clean install, `starting from latest version`, seems easiest solution.

Comment: python is latest version, and I don't think I ever installed python 3.8 because when I looked at my list of python versions, it showed "3.9-32", "3.9", "3.10", and "3.11".

Comment: Why dont you not remove it all and install wat need? That definitely should help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one python interpreter, things may become messy.
The best way to do that is by using virtual environments.You can use native python [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-environments/) or even [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html).

Or you could call pip module using the desired interpreter:

```
c:\...path_to_python_3_11\python.exe -m pip install my_module
```

Comment: It said it worked, but when I went to use my python file, it said requests was missing, and once I tried to type "pip install requests", it said pip could not be found. "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: How are you using the python file? Are you double-clicking or calling by command line?  You are probably calling the wrong interpreter.

Comment: calling by command line